# Создание нового интерфейса\типа на основе generic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Я хочу создавать новый тип данных на основе объекта и его интерфейса
В интерфейсе ключи могут быть не обязательными( | undefined), но если они есть в объекте, то должны стать обязательными.
Пример:

```
export type MakeRequiredType<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & {
    [P in K]-?: T[P];
};
interface personInterface {
    id?: number;
    name?: string;
    title?: string;
}

const person: personInterface = {
    id: 2,
    name: "John",
};

type OptionalToRequiredData = MakeRequiredType<personInterface, keyof typeof person>;//Получение нового типа

const resultPerson: OptionalToRequiredData = {
    id: 2,//Это поле становится обязательным
    name: 'John',//Это поле становится обязательным
    title: ''//Все ещё не обязательное поле, так как в person его нет
};
```

Сейчас минус в том, что берется keyof typeof person, то есть тип ключей из интерфейса, а не из объекта, к которому этот интерфейс относится, поэтому все поля становятся обязательными.

Я знаю, что к полям можно обращаться и с помощью person.name! и person.name?, мне нужно именно изменить тип данных

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы и `title` был обязательным? В том число все поля которые будут добавлятся и которые отсутсвуют на самом объекте. И этот символ `-?` если я правильно понял для того чтобы сделать все поля обязательными?

Comment: Тот код, который я прислал действительно делает все поля из интерфейса обязательными, а мне нужно, чтоб он делал обязательными из этого интерфейса только те ключи, которые есть в объекте, то есть в примере выше, поле title в объекте нет=> это поле остаётся необязательным, а все остальные становятся обязательными

Comment: А проблема заключается в том, что я беру typeof keyof person, то есть ключи не из самого person, а из его интерфейса